# C# A method that will accept any List<enum> and return a string array

Tags: c#, .net

There is an incredibly longer story to why I'm actually doing this, so I'm sure there is a better way as an overall approach.  I don't have time to refactor the entire base structure and I want to minimize about 20k lines in the library to a method.  What I want to be able to do is take any `List<Enum>` and return a string[].  My example is below, I'm sure I'm probably missing some sort of reflection.  Thanks!

```
public enum ActivityEnum
    {
        ID,
        ACTIVITYTYPEID,
        CAMPAIGNID,
        BUDGETID,
        LISTID
    }


public enum ActivityAttributeEnum
    {
        ID,
        ACTIVITYID,
        ACTIVITYATTRIBUTE,
        ENABLED,
        CREATEDBY,
        CREATEDDATE,
        LASTUPDATEBY,
        LASTUPDATEDATE
    }


public string[] myStrings(List<activtyEnum> activityEnums)
        {
            var array = new string[activityEnums.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < activityEnums.Count; i++)
                array[i] = activityEnums[i].ToString();

            return array;

        }
```

What I'm unsure of is how to accept any enum. In my example I have activityEnum, but I want the method to accept both ActivityAttribtueEnum and ActivityEnum.  There are about 600 enums, so a generic way would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: The minimal change to the function you already have, to make it generic, is to write `public string[] myStrings<T>(List<T> activityEnums) { ... }` and keep the exact same body of the method. The first occurrence of `<T>` between the method name and the `(` declares that this method is generic and has one type parameter which I called `T` (you can use any name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
private string[] GetNames<TEnum>(List<TEnum> enums) where TEnum : Enum
{
    return enums.Select(e => e.ToString()).ToArray();
}
```

You really ought to declare the parameter as type `IEnumerable<TEnum>` because that will work with a `List<T>`, an array, the result of a LINQ query and various other list types too.

Note that any list can have its items converted to a `string` array in this way too, so there's not really a need to to constrain the item type to be an `enum`. It won't actually hurt to define the method without a generic constraint. You might just want to change the name in that case, because the values returned might not be names.

Comment: TY very much.  What is the <TEnum? after GetNames called?  I'd love to learn more about that.  Also the where TEnum : Enm? @user18387401

Comment: The `<TEnum>` is specifying that this is a generic method with one generic type parameter named `TEnum`. It's just like the `<T>` on `List<T>`. The `where TEnum : Enum` is a generic type constraint, specifying that any type used in that context must be or inherit the `Enum` class, which all `enums` do. `TEnum` is used rather than just `T` to indicate that constraint, but that is not necessary. It could be `GetNames<T>(List<T> enums) where T : Enum`. You probably ought to do some reading on generics in general.

Comment: I understand the TEnum which makes  completele sense.  When did the syntax of where TEnum: Enum come about at the end of the method what is that called?

Comment: @JL1, I already answered that in my previous comment.

Comment: _” When did the syntax of where TEnum: Enum come about ”_ -  C# 7.3 I think